# How to overwrite one object in a binary file?

Tags: c#, object, serialization, binaryfiles

I have to specifically do user registration through a binary file in this case, so unfortunately, I have to do it this way. C#.

I have my user registration set up so that the user object is appended onto the end of a .bin file.  The user login takes in all the users in this file into a list and searches for a user with the same username and password.  However, I want my users to be able to edit their profile, so I want a function that will re-save their object to the file.  This is what I have at the minute:

```
BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (Stream bFile = File.Open("../../data/UserData.bin", FileMode.Append))
{
    bFormatter.Serialize(bFile, Settings.User);
}
```

Surely though this will only append the updated object to the end of the file leaving 2 versions of the same object though?  Anyone any suggestions on how to go about this so it updates the existing object in the binary file?

Comment: The easiest way is to make each user record the exact same size. Then it's very easy to seek between user records in the file (userIndex * recordSize). Otherwise you're going to have to do a lot of work with indexing and so forth or just rewrite the entire file every time there's an edit.

Comment: Could you just deserialize the UserData file, make changes to user object(s) and then serialize the entire thing? In other words, overwrite the prior file with the newly serialized version?

Comment: How do I make them the same size?

Comment: I know you said you have to do it that way, but really? Do you really HAVE to do it that way? Because it's not making much sense. Personally, I would use a SQL-CE database. But that's easy to say without knowing anything about the context.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

**1)** If you know that the specific number of bytes for that user object will ALWAYS remain constant then simply overwrite those specific bytes with the new data.

**2)** If the number of each bytes used per record and stored in the file can change then you can overwrite that specific users record (bytes) with zero's or null and append the new record. Your file size will continue to increase.

**3)** If the number of each bytes used per record and stored in the file can change then read back all the data, modify it and create a new ".bin" file.

**4)** If each user record is a set size then simply overwrite those bytes (i.e find start position in file and overwrite x amount of bytes.

Comment: There are *many* more options than those few (when dealing at the raw data level), but for starters..